# c# button click input value return empty

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to get value from input in code behind the problem is value always return empty "" when im using master page but its working fine without master page

html

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <form action="#" method="post" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="email" placeholder="email"  />
        </form>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRegister" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = email.Value; //retun empty " "
}
```

Comment: This question is not detailed. You must add more detail. Where is the button register? Where you call them. It is a mvc project? which version you are using?

Comment: asp.net web App

Comment: Will you edit your post?

Comment: i did i wish thats help

Comment: UpdatePanel implies web forms. In web forms, _you cannot have your own html form elements in the markup_. There's the main form element for the page and that's it.

Comment: Did you use breakpoint. Use a test variable that takes the email.Value and see what email returns to you? Maybe it has not value parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just removed other

```
 <form action="#" method="post" >
```

from MasterPage and its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
<div>
   <form action="#" method="post" >
      
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
 ...
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"</asp:TextBox>
....
    </form>
```

and get value

```
var email = txtEmail.Text;
```

Comment: im already have ScriptManager  in the master page

Comment: @DarwieshMustafa Ok, then don't  put it again

Comment: yes of cours , i can't understand im using VS2015 and this code was working before in old apps i made

Comment: @DarwieshMustafa  What are you using is 2005 version, I am not sure if you were born then

Comment: Visual Studio 2015